# How can we get the pivot columns name in a query?

Tags: oracle

our requirement is to get the pivot columns values and do the sum of all pivot's columns value and  show the

Below is the query, in which first I get the all columns values  to make the pivot columns dynamic and put these values into `colms` variable. Then I used this `colms` variable value into pivot query but I want to the sum of all pivot columns and show it in a column. (PFB pink color column is the sum of all pivot columns value)

[image]

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TIMETRACK.PRC_GPD_TIMESHEET_DATA_PROJECT_TYPE(
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
v_sqlstmt varchar2(10000);
colms VARCHAR2(20000);
BEGIN

select listagg('''' || PROJECT_TYPE ||''' as "' || PROJECT_TYPE || '"'  , ',' ) within group (order by PROJECT_TYPE) 
            into colms
            from (SELECT distinct tp.PROJECT_TYPE as PROJECT_TYPE FROM tt_timesheet_details ttd
                     JOIN tt_project tp ON ttd.PROJ = tp.PROJ
                     JOIN tt_users tu ON ttd.RN = tu.RN
                     LEFT JOIN tt_element te ON te.ELEMENT = tu.RC02 AND te.category = 'RES WORK TYPE'
                     WHERE tu.status = 'A'
                     AND week = TO_DATE ('8/15/2021', 'MM/dd/yyyy'));  
                     --dbms_output.put_line(v_sqlstmt); 
                     
                     v_sqlstmt := 'select * from  ( SELECT ttd.TOTAL,
                     tp.PROJECT_TYPE,
                     tu.ntuser
                         "NTID",
                     PKG_USER.FNC_CONSTRUCT_FULLNAME (tu.LNAME,
                                                      tu.FNAME,
                                                      tu.MINITIAL)
                         "Full Name",
                     tu.supervisor_name,                     
                     te.DS
                         "RWT",
                     te.PW_OVERHEAD_RWT
                         "OVERHEAD_RWT"
                FROM tt_timesheet_details ttd
                     JOIN tt_project tp ON ttd.PROJ = tp.PROJ
                     JOIN tt_users tu ON ttd.RN = tu.RN
                     LEFT JOIN tt_element te
                         ON     te.ELEMENT = tu.RC02
                            AND te.category = ''RES WORK TYPE''
               WHERE     tu.status = ''A''
                     AND week = TO_DATE (''8/15/2021'', ''MM/dd/yyyy'')
                    
                     AND PKG_OBS.FNC_GETPARENTDS (tu.RC01, ''DIVISION'') =
                         ''D-GLOBAL PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT (1010)'') -- and  tu.RC02 = ''RA-110'')
             PIVOT (SUM (TOTAL)
                   FOR PROJECT_TYPE
                   IN (' || colms || '))';
                   
      OPEN p_cursor FOR v_sqlstmt;
    
END PRC_GPD_TIMESHEET_DATA_PROJECT_TYPE;
```